# Is there an easy way to ingest OBO formatted files into RDF4J without using OWL API?

Tags: rdf, owl, owl-api, rdf4j

I want to be able to be able to ingest OBO formatted files into RDF4J in addition to Turtle, RDF/XML, etc...

It looks like OWL API has some parsers to do so but I am trying to avoid using OWL API. Are there other known ways of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the OBO parsers I'm aware of use OWL API.
You could take the source code for the obo module and replace all OWLAPI references with RDF4j - there are RDF4J adapters in the rio module to use for reference. But it is not a small undertaking.